# How can I use same decorator stacked in python?

Tags: python

I have a decorator that checks the file validation

```py
def check_file(*args, **kwargs):
    def wrapper(f):
        file_path = os.path.join(kwargs['path'], kwargs['file_name'])
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print("{} Exist".format(kwargs['file_name'])
        else:
            print("{} Not Exist".format(kwargs['file_name'])
        f()
    return wrapper
```

The function I want to have decorator on,

```py
@check_file(path=os.getcwd(), file_name="foo.txt")
@check_file(path=os.getcwd(), file_name="bar.txt")
@check_file(path=os.getcwd(), file_name="hello.txt")
@check_file(path=os.getcwd(), file_name="world.txt")
def read_file():
    print("It will be decorated")
```

I know decorator has an execution order, however, it seems like it only execute the last one("world.txt"). How can I execute all same decorators?

*I am using Python3.7

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Since it has `print`, it only prints out the last file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
def check_file(*args, **kwargs):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper():
            file_path = os.path.join(kwargs['path'], kwargs['file_name'])
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                print("{} Exist".format(kwargs['file_name'])
            else:
                print("{} Not Exist".format(kwargs['file_name'])
            f()
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

When you use decorators with arguments you have to wrap your decorator function around another function which excepts those arguments.

Comment: The wrapper **should call** the wrapped function.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. Updated the answer.